# react native android unrecognized

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Before I run `react-native run-android`, I run `react-native android` to set up project to Android. Well, here are my common directory

```
09/02/2019  02:14 PM    <DIR>          .
09/02/2019  02:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/02/2019  09:27 AM                74 .gitignore
08/02/2019  09:27 AM                 3 .watchmanconfig
08/02/2019  09:27 AM             3,186 App.js
08/02/2019  09:27 AM               726 app.json
08/02/2019  09:27 AM    <DIR>          assets
08/02/2019  09:27 AM               107 babel.config.js
08/02/2019  09:27 AM    <DIR>          components
09/02/2019  02:01 PM               273 generate-android-project.js
08/02/2019  09:27 AM             1,032 google-services.json
08/02/2019  09:27 AM             1,074 LICENSE
09/02/2019  02:22 PM    <DIR>          node_modules
09/02/2019  02:14 PM           300,591 package-lock.json
09/02/2019  02:21 PM               682 package.json
08/02/2019  09:27 AM                61 README.md
08/02/2019  09:27 AM    <DIR>          screens
08/02/2019  09:27 AM    <DIR>          utils
09/02/2019  02:21 PM           254,814 yarn.lock
```

When I trying to

> react-native android

this message appears

```
Unrecognized command 'android'
Run react-native --help to see list of all available commands
```

Then here are my solution

1. Trying `react-native upgrade` 
   Not working
2. Trying `yarn add react-native-cli`
   Not working
3. Trying `yarn`
   Also not working
4. `yarn add android`
   Not working
5. reference this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9312#issuecomment-239254800)

   ```
       const fs = require('fs');
       const generate = require('react-native/local-cli/generate/generate.js');

       generate([
         '--platform', 'android',
         '--project-path', process.cwd(),
         '--project-name', JSON.parse(
           fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8')
         ).name,
       ]);
   ```

   `node generate-android-project.js`
   Same result, not working
6. `react-native upgrade` 
   not working
7. `npm install` 
   still doesn't works
8. `npm run run:android`

   ```
   npm ERR! missing script: run:android
   ```

How to run my project properly on Android Emulator or Real Devices?

Thanks

Update 1 : `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "start:android": "adb shell am start -n com.airbnb.android.react.maps.example/.MainActivity",
    "run:android": "./gradlew installDebug && npm run start:android"
```

Comment: This is not an android problem, this is a react native "problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start a project with

```
react-native init yourapp
```

Then run this while your mobile phone is connected or emulator is turned on

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: we had done with that, those are basic knowledge to use `react-native`

Comment: Well that is how you do it, you don't run "react-native android". Are you getting an error message with "react-native init yourapp"? You have to create a project before you can run it. When you want to run an already created react-native project on Android, you cd into the project and run it with "react-native run-android"

Comment: So try, this and then say which error you are getting. Thanks.